# Using contextvars instead of wrapper classes to store additional data

Tags: python

Let's say we have class with data:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

And collection class:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, foos):
        self.foos = []
        if foos:
            self.foos = foos

    def set_z(self):
        for foo in self.foos:
            foo.z = randint()

    def print_z(self):
        print([foo.z for foo in self.foos])
```

Basic stuff. Now the question.

How can we store additional variable `z` in each object of `class Foo`, but different for each instance of `class Bar` this object is in.

What I want to do:

```
>>> f1 = Foo(x=13, y=42)
>>> f2 = Foo(x=-3, y=21)

>>> b1 = Bar(foos=[f1, f2])
>>> b2 = Bar(foos=[f1, f2])

>>> b1.set_z()
>>> b2.set_z()

>>> b1.print_z()
[9, 11]
>>> b2.print_z()
[32, 8]
```

First thought is to make wrapper class like this:

```
class FooWrapper:
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo
        self.z = None
```

And change Bar to automatically wrap each object:

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, foos):
        self.foos = []
        if foos:
            self.foos = [FooWrapper(foo) for foo in foos]
```

Is there maybe cleaner way without writting additional class? It not look bad here, but when there is lot of different properties in both base class and wrapper class, it becomes messy. Changing `bar.foos` into dict is not an option, since it's not guaranteed foos will all be hashable.

But now looking at Python 3.7 docs I read about contextvars. It seems like this is something that can be used in this case, but I have problem grasping this concept. Can I set every instance of `class Bar` as context and write `z` as contextvar inside `class Foo`? Will it be reasonable?

Comment: Now I think there can be `__getattr__` method used to expose `Foo` methods and properties in `FooWrapper` class. It will be cleaner to access data. But maybe there is better way.

Answer (score 0):

An instance can only have a single value for a given attribute at any given time, but as long as you're accessing this "attribute" through the container, you can store the values on the container.

One way is to construct a new list in which each item is a 2-tuple consisting of a foo and a dict. The dict can then hold the z values in a manner that supports adding other  attributes and values.

```
from random import randint


class Foo:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


class Bar:

    def __init__(self, foos):
        self.foos_with_benefits = [(foo, {}) for foo in foos]

    def set_attribute(self, name):
        for foo, attributes in self.foos_with_benefits:
            attributes[name] = randint(1, 100)

    def print_attribute(self, name):
        print([attributes[name] for _, attributes in self.foos_with_benefits])

    def set_z(self):
        self.set_attribute('z')

    def print_z(self):
        self.print_attribute('z')
```

It performs along the lines of what you were requesting:

```
>>> f1 = Foo(x=13, y=42)

>>> f2 = Foo(x=-3, y=21)

>>> b1 = Bar(foos=[f1, f2])

>>> b2 = Bar(foos=[f1, f2])

>>> b1.set_z()

>>> b2.set_z()

>>> b1.print_z()
[81, 19]

>>> b2.print_z()
[66, 99]
```

As for contextvars, they don't seem well-suited to this kind of use case. For one thing, the value of a contextvar can vary across async contexts, not across instances within the same async context. If you're interested in learning more about how you might use contextvars, I've written a context manager for using contextvars on the fly: [FlexContext](https://gist.github.com/elidchan/2c944d46c2d857fd592b095b55d8a60f).